# Debug javascript in opera mini

Tags: javascript, remote-debugging, opera-mini

How do i debug javascript in opera mini?

I have already installed opera mini emulator.

can someone help me how do i debug javascript remotely with dragonfly (firebug equivalent of opera)?

My script does in work in all other browser but not in opera mini

Answer (score 3):

Opera Mini [supports](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-and-javascript/) console API like this:

```
server:console?post=http://url/to/your/script
```

**OR**

You can dump your log data to source and [get source](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2011/09/19/viewing-and-exporting-source-in-opera-mini) using this command(this fill display source code of current/last page for your device):

```
server:source
```

**OR**

Use remote `console` services like [jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com/). You add script tag with jsconsole script and key. After this use this key on jsconsole [site](http://jsconsole.com/) to get the log.

NB: jsconsole script rewrites console.log calling via ajax request

Comment: `server:source` is using without any url, just type this in address bar

Answer (score 0):

There is, at least for now, no support for debugging a javascript directly in Opera Mini.

You can use `document.write` to output progress/debug messanges, that is about the extent of debugging posibilities.

Could you point to the script, or at least describe what it is trying to do?

Opera Mini is fairly different from a normal browser, scripts are run on the transcoding servers, and the result of the run is then passed to the client, which can not in fact run scripts.

The client can then pass on clicks and some other events to the script when the user interact with the page, which might change the state/look of the page on the server, which is then sent to the client.

Comment: Script does just login to the site, http://clikstyle.net/wp-admin it does work in all other browser but not in opera mini